# Slider run in offline/localhost but not run in online/server

Tags: javascript, slideshow, jquery-ui-slider

I write a JavaScript code for slider. This code run in localhost or offline. But it is not run in online or my server. I use this code. please help me. I try but not solve it. where is my wrong?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var imagecount=1;
            var total=5;

            function slide(x){
                var Image = document.getElementById('img');
                imagecount = imagecount + x;
                if(imagecount > total)
                    {
                        imagecount=1;
                    }
                if (imagecount < 1) 
                    {
                        imagecount = total;
                    }
                Image.src = "img/image" + imagecount + ".jpg";
            }
            window.setInterval(function slideA(){
                var Image = document.getElementById('img');
                imagecount = imagecount + 1;
                if(imagecount > total)
                    {
                        imagecount=1;
                    }
                if (imagecount < 1) 
                    {
                        imagecount = total;
                    }
                Image.src = "img/image" + imagecount + ".jpg";
            },5000);
        </script>
```

Comment: I use  <script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>   &    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> before writing code. but not work it.

Comment: check the javascript console from your online server to see if it reports any errors.